# Edit text content for multilingual website via admin

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm a beginner with Symfony 4 and I would like to create an admin on my multilingual website, where I can edit the text on all page and for all available languages, and not using the Symfony toolbar in dev mode.
I have not yet started the development of the site, but I wonder about the upstream questions to know if it would be better to go through Symfony or Wordpress for this detail for example.

So I'm asking your help ! Do you know tutorials or do you have any ideas on how to create an admin like this with Symfony 4 ?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [a2lix/TranslationFormBundle](https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle)

Check their website site for example at :

https://a2lix.fr/bundles/translation-form/3.x.html